# Regular value of $g \circ f$ is a regular value of $g$

Tags: differential-topology

Given smooth maps $f: X \to Y, g: Y \to Z$, where $X, Y, Z$ are boundaryless, compact manifolds of dimension $n$, is the statement in the title true?

Comment: Do you know the chain rule?

Comment: Yeah, so for any regular value $z$ of $g \circ f$, if $x \in (g \circ f)^{-1}(z)$,  then $D(g \circ f)_x  = Dg_y \circ Df_x$, where $y = f(x)$ So $Dg_y$ is an isomorphism, but that doesn't seem sufficient to show that $z$ is a regular value for $g$.

Comment: So how could it fail to be a regular value?  In your argument you have $Dg$ at $f(x)$ is onto.   What more do you need?

Comment: So, an element $z \in Z$ is a regular value if for every $y \in g^{-1}(z)$, $Dg_y$ is onto.  The chain rule only seems to show that $Dg_y$ is onto only when $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in X$

Comment: Correct.  So now that you have this insight, what are you going to do with it?  It's everything you need to answer your question.

Comment: So is the proof of problem 4 incorrect here, since it assumes that $z$ is a regular value of $g$ http://www.stanford.edu/~ronen/math147/midtermSol.pdf

Answer (score 1):

For the definition of regular value that I know ("a point in the complement of the set of critical values"), the claim is clearly false. Consider  maps $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)\equiv 1$ and $g(x)=x^2$. Then $0$ is a regular value of $g\circ f$ (vacuously, since it's not attained at all), but not of $g$. One can modify this example to satisfy the "boundaryless, compact" part, but I won't bother to: it's clear that the matter is local.

Even if we are to take the more restrictive definition of a regular value, requiring it to be attained, the claim is still false. Again on $\mathbb R$, take $f(x)=\tan^{-1} x$   and $g(x)=x(x-5)^2$. Now $0$ is a regular value of $g\circ f$, since $g(f(x))=0$ only when $x=0$, and the derivative of $g\circ f$ at $0$ does not vanish. But $0$ is not a regular value of $g$, because $g(5)=0$ and $g'(5)=0$.

The claim is true, and easy to prove, for surjective maps.